# How to center the mat-chips in a stacked mat-chip-list

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-9

This is how the chips are stacked right now:

[image: https://imgur.com/hf2J8Xa]

The space on the left is clearly less then on the right. How can i center the chips so that the margins on both sides are even? I've tried using custom css classes with `text-align: center` and `vertical-align:middle` but none of that worked.

EDIT: For reference here is the code:

```
<mat-form-field  class = "chiplist" *ngIf="advancedFilterList.length > 0">
<mat-chip-list class="mat-chip-list-stacked" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let advancedFilter of advancedFilterList" [selectable]="selectable" 
        [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(advancedFilter)" (click)="changeUnitSymbolAndPopulateFieldsWithSelectedFilterData(advancedFilter)">
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>  
        <div [innerHTML]="getFullFilterDescription(advancedFilter)"></div>
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should delete the class "**mat-chip-list-stacked**", since it has a width of 100%, so you would already see the mat-chip centered. If you want to add CSS, create your own class and add the corresponding styles

Example: [mat-chip center](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-chip-default-select-4q5pjm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: did you check your stackblitz example before posting it? The chips appear horizontally while i need them to be stacked vertically. Also removing mat-chip-list-stacked class doesent change anything, it still doesent center

Comment: I had not been completely saved. For next time, attach a stackblitz.

Comment: On my side I needed this line from
css file ( justify-content: center;)

Thanks